# Android Lollipop Sends Multiple BroadcastReceivers for Telephone State Changes

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Up to android kitkat phone state broadcast receiver works fine. In android lolipop phone state broadcast receiver sending multiple broadcast. Is there any thing changed in Android Lolipop.

```
public class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    Log.d("PhoneState", state);
  }
 }  
} 

  <receiver android:name="com.phonestate.PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: i noticed there is an extra sent with the intent  called subscription, and seems to be either 1 or 9223372036854775807. My guess is, a bug?

Comment: the number is Long.MAX_VALUE. Have you find why this is happening?

Comment: I posted a bug report for this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161508

Comment: Thanks @muzikant for giving the reference

Comment: It gets worse... with the Android 5.1 update the `subscription` extra is now Integer and gets the value of Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend this solution:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  long subId = intent.getLongExtra("subscription", Long.MIN_VALUE);
  if(subId < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    // hurray, this is called only once on all operating system versions!
  }
}
```

it works on both 4.x a 5.x and should be forward-compatible. For more details please refer to my blog:

http://www.skoumal.net/en/android-duplicated-phone-state-broadcast-on-lollipop/